# What are the best solutions to replace kubernetes port-forward

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, rancher

I am working on `rancher` server, `k3s` to improve my knowledge on these solutions.

I want to expose container services on LAN network, this is why I used `kubectl port-forward`.

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace=ns-name --address LAN-IP service/hello 30104:8080
```

But I can see in several web resources that is not a reliable solution, just for local testing purpose.

I tried to replace them by ingress but I am a bit lost between `ingress`, `DNS` and `nginx-ingress` in addition to `rancher` component.
I understood than `load balancer` need a cloud provider, to have a public IP for instance, and handle the `<pending>` state of load balancer.

Can you highlight me on how replace `port-forward` in LAN without a cloud provider?

**[edit @Rajesh Dutta]**

I already use `NodePort`, but, without port-forward the service is exposed as `NODE_IP:PORT`, not `LAN_IP:PORT`. My need is to join it from outside of the cluster.

So this is what i did :

1 - create deployment

```
kubectl create deployment hello --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0 --port=8080 --replicas=2
```

2 - expose deployment(create service)

```
kubectl expose deployment hello --type=NodePort
```

3 - forward service

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace=ns-name --address local-ip service/hello 30104:8080
```

[IP schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez4Vc.png)

Now, considering that i will have several service, i would find the best ways to replace port-forward.

Answer (score 2):

To start with I would recommend to use NodePort service. This will expose your application to a NodePort(30000-32767). Later if you want you can choose to switch to ingress.

Assuming that you are trying with a deployment type object

**command:**

`kubectl expose deployment deployment-name --type=NodePort --port=8080 --target-port=<rancher server port>`

Comment: I used NodePort but service will be accessible only by Node IP not on local network IP.